# Ruby and windows commandline

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

I am running a ruby test script of the form `rake drive:unit_tests:load_data_parameters here` in windows cmd or commandline tool. This test displays some output on the screen. I am trying to run this test from a batch or .bat file. I also want the bat file to output everything from the screen to a text file. When I execute the same command as a variable in a bat file, nothing happens.

How do I solve my problems ?

I tried this -

```
@Echo on
set code = rake drive:unit_tests:load_data_parameters here
%code%
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you uses `Echo on`?

You need use `set code=...` instead `set code =...`

Then for redirect any text output from program, use:

```
( %code% ) >MyTextFile.txt
Type MyTextFile.txt
```

Comment: `set code=...` instead `set code =...` Is the same thing. I  tried the brackets nd I got the error `)` was unexpected at this time.

Comment: When you try use `set code = ...` (only in batch files) breaks the next content. For avoid it, is required use the equal sign with no space at variable name.